# Why can't char** be the return type of the following function in C++?

Tags: c++, c, function, char, return-type

I have the following function in C++ :

```
char** f()
{
    char (*v)[10] = new char[5][10];
    return v;
}
```

Visual studio 2008 says the following:

```
error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'char (*)[10]' to 'char **'
```

What exactly should the return type to be, in order for this function to work?

Comment: could you not just do char** v = new char[5][10];?

Comment: Do you want to return a function-pointer-array or a multidimensional array of `char`?

Comment: Because a pointer to pointers is not the same as a pointer to arrays.

Comment: @Nobody: What do function pointers have to do with it?

Comment: @Tomalak: Oh I think I saw too much paranthesis ^^

Comment: @Nobody: Yes, I think you did ;)

Comment: @user761184: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4810676#4810676) FAQ entry. The part entitled "Conversions" answers your question. Now, if you'll excuse me, I have to go back to watching out for the inevitable onslaught of dangerously incorrect answers being posted to this question.

Comment: @Nobody, I wish to return a multi-dimensional array of char.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`char**` is not the same type as `char (*)[10]`. Both of these are incompatible types and so `char (*)[10]` cannot be implicitly converted to `char**`. Hence the compilation error.

The return type of the function looks very ugly. You have to write it as:

```
char (*f())[10]
{
    char (*v)[10] = new char[5][10];
    return v;
}
```

Now it [compiles](http://ideone.com/VfQYF).

Or you can use `typedef` as:

```
typedef char carr[10];

carr* f()
{
    char (*v)[10] = new char[5][10];
    return v;
}
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/70AUP).

---

Basically, `char (*v)[10]` defines a pointer to a `char` array of size 10. It's the same as the following:

```
 typedef char carr[10]; //carr is a char array of size 10

 carr *v; //v is a pointer to array of size 10
```

So your code becomes equivalent to this:

```
carr* f()
{
    carr *v = new carr[5];
    return v;
}
```

---

[`cdecl.org`](http://cdecl.org/) helps here:

- `char v[10]` reads as `declare v as array 10 of char`
- `char (*v)[10]` reads as `declare v as pointer to array 10 of char`

Comment: You didn't answer the question.

Comment: @Tomalak: The question is `What exactly should the return type to be, in order for this function to work?`. So how may post doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @Codo: Did you see the link to ideone code which compiles it fine? Also, there is no *function* pointers.

Comment: If you look at the title, you'll see that the OP would also like to know why `char**` is not correct, which is only sensible.

Comment: @Codo: There are no function pointers. Why is everybody going on about function pointers? Read your C++ book again... :(

Comment: @Tomalak: I thought it was very obvious from my post when I explained what `char (*)[10]` is. Anyway, I added a little explanation at the top for you.

Comment: Meh, it still doesn't even come close to describing the difference between `char (*)[10]` and `char**` in this context, which is the real crux of this question I think. And your `char v[10]` at the end of your answer is not mentioned anywhere in the question at all!

Comment: @Tomalak: I know that. I added `char v[10]` so that he can compare how both are read. <philosophy> **trying to explain the unknown by comparing it with known** </philosophy>.  Also, I explained in brief that `char(*)[10]` and `char **` are two different types!

Comment: @Nawaz: But the OP already knows they're different types; the question was about finding out in what way they differ such that a conversion cannot be performed.

Comment: @Tomalak: Are you the OP? I read his question, and its not `"in what way they differ such that a conversion cannot be performed."`. He is more interested in the solution as to how to fix it, rather than going into detail of memory representation.

Comment: @Nawaz: A full answer _explains_ why the original approach failed, and then provides the solution. Come on you know this! And it's still clear that he knows they are two distinct types; he just doesn't know _why_ they are two distinct types. So telling him that they are two distinct types is not useful.

Comment: @Tomalak: I asked you: are you the OP? Let him speak. From his question, I don't feel he wants memory representation of each types, and then the explanation.

Comment: @Nawak: I'm obviously not the OP. You can see that from the difference in the names. Obviously we disagree on the content of the question, which is fine, and we should leave that there. "Let him speak" is hardly useful though: we all have commenting ability here.

Comment: @Tomalak: I know your answer is correct and complete, and explains everything, even though it does not say **how** to write the return type.

Comment: I'm the OP. I wanted both questions answered. However, I admit that the way I wrote my post can mislead some people into believing that the second question was what really mattered and that the one in the title wasn't so important. @Nawaz Your explanations were pretty clear to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

A pointer to pointers is not the same as a pointer to arrays.

[image: very crude diagram]

<sup>(In particular, notice how `sizeof(*ptr1)` is `sizeof(char)*6`, whereas `sizeof(*ptr3)` is `sizeof(char*)` — this has serious ramifications for pointer arithmetic.)</sup>

---

`new char[5][10]` gives you a `char (*)[10]` (which has absolutely nothing to do with function pointers, by the way), because the pointers and chars are laid out in that fashion in memory (my second example).

This is *not* the same as `char**` (which represents a different layout), so a conversion between the two makes no sense; hence, it is disallowed.

So your function's return type must be `char (*)[10]`:

```
char (*f())[10] {
    char (*v)[10] = new char[5][10];
    return v;
}
```

Of course, this is really ugly, so you're far better off with a `std::vector<std::string>`.

---

[This FAQ entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4810676#4810676) explains it best, under the title "Conversions".

Comment: That visualization is key to understanding the difference. Note that I would second the recommendation of the `std::vector<std::string>` as it's what you probably mean if dealing with a set of strings.

Comment: @Tomalak: `(In particular, notice how sizeof(ptr1) is sizeof(char), whereas sizeof(ptr2) is sizeof(char)*6 )` . Wrong. Both `sizeof(ptr1)` and `sizeof(ptr2)` will be equal to `sizeof(void*)`.

Comment: +1 for showing why pointer decay doesn't work the same way here as it would with `char[N]` -> `char*`.

Comment: The first *"[One or more]"* are both incorrect - `ptr1` and `ptr2` are each a single pointer.  `ptr2` is *"A pointer to one or more arrays of six char"*, and `ptr1` is *"A pointer to one or more pointers to one or more char"*.

Comment: @caf: Not incorrect, though possibly misleading. But when you have a pointer, without further context you can't say for sure that you can't increment it within a block. That was the intention there. It merely happens to be the case that the graphical examples demonstrate the case where the first "[One or more]" evaluates to "one" and the last "[One or more]" evaluates to "more".

Comment: @Tomalak Gerek'kal: That incrementing applies to the objects *that it points to*.  There is still exactly one root pointer in both those examples - in the `ptr1` case there is only two levels of "one or more", not three.  In the `ptr2` case there is one level, but it attaches to the arrays not the base pointer.  The arrays themselves in the second example should also be shown as sequentially arranged, as they must be to be referenced as `ptr2[n]`.

Comment: @caf: In the specific examples, yes. Not in the general case of `char**`, say. The graphics are the specific examples; the captions are the general description. Perhaps I should make that clearer.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: An object declared as simply `char **` is *always* a single pointer object.  If you want N of them, you have to instead declare it as an array: `char **[N]`.

Comment: @caf: Approval on the new diagram please :)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: That looks good now.  It might also be worth showing that the three second-level pointers in the second example are sequential in memory.

Comment: BTW forgive my use of the variable name `ptr2`. Of course an array is not a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

Because `char**` and `char (*)[10]` are two different types. `char**` is a pointer to pointer(to `char`), while `char (*)[10]` is a pointer to an array(of size 10) of `char`. Resultantly, the *moving step* of `char**` is `sizeof(void *)` bytes which is 4 bytes on win32 platform, and the *moving step* of `char (*)[10]` is `sizeof(char) * 10` bytes.

***Example***

```
   char *c = NULL;
   char **v = &c;
   cout << typeid(v).name() << endl;
   cout << (void*)v << endl;
   v += 1;
   cout << (void*)v << endl;

   char d[10];
   char (*u)[10] = &d;
   cout << typeid(u).name() << endl;
   cout << (void*)u << endl;
   u += 1;
   cout << (void*)u << endl;
```

***Output***

```
char * *
0034FB1C
0034FB20
char (*)[10]
001AFC50
001AFC5A
```

To use `char (*)[10]` as a function's return type(or as input/output parameter of the function), the easiest and most readable way is to use a `typedef`:

```
// read from inside-out: PTRTARR is a pointer, and, it points to an array, of chars.
typedef char (*PTRTARR)[10];
```

Note that it can easily be mixed up with `typedef` of an ***array of pointers***, if not careful:

```
// operator[] has higher precedence than operator*,
// PTRARR is an array of pointers to char.
typedef char *PTRARR[10];
```

***Reference***

[Arrays and Pointers](http://tonywearme.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/62/)

Comment: Your answer seems a bit more complicated than it needs to be, @Eric Z, but I kind of get what you're saying. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, just hope you not only understand WHAT, but also WHY & HOW;)

Comment: It's precisely as complicated as the subject under discussion, @conectionist. It's worthwhile studying all the answers!