# How to convert vector< vector<string> > to char **

Tags: c++, stl

How to convert a

```
vector< vector<string> >
```

to a

```
struct _Struct_3
{
public:
    char **__ptr;
    int __size;
};
```

?

Comment: Is this C++ or C? If you have to interface with C then you're going to have to do a bunch of `malloc`s and copies (and pray you get the cleanup right to not leak memory). If it's C++ just don't do that. Ever.

Comment: What is your question? should we write the code for you? then you want rentacoder.com. What did you try to far, where are your problems, what is the concrete point you are having trouble with?

Comment: Problem underspecified. A vector of vectors of strings is a three-dimensional char array, not two-dimensional.

Comment: A char** is either a double array of chars or an array of c strings (char*).  As far as I know you need a char ***_ptr to be able to do what you want to.  Besides, the size only allows you to keep track of the size of one of them.  Unless you use another struct that contains an array of _Struct_3.

Comment: @leetNightshade: A `char**` is **never** "a double array of chars".

Comment: @lightness-races-in-orbit  Actually, I politely disagree.  A char** is an array of c strings, which itself is an array of chars.  Look at this:  char** blah = new char*[5];
 for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  blah[i] = new char[5];

 blah[4][4] = 'c';//accessing it as a double array of chars

Comment: @leetNightshade: Nonsense. A `char**` is not an array but a pointer. Even if you assume that the pointer points to the first element of an array, that's an array of _pointers [possibly to arrays]_, not of arrays. There is a very important distinction. Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/a/7139014/560648

Comment: @lightness-races-in-orbit I already knew that it's technically just a pointer, but abstractly it allows you to access a double array of chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  iterate over first vector and then

```
vector<string> tokens;
char* args;                                                                                                 
args = new char [tokens.size()];                                                                                           
copy( tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), args);
```

Answer (score 1):

`vector<string>` can be put into a `char **__ptr`, so you  would want to put the `vector<vector<string>>` into a `_Struct_3*` right actually? You would simply iterate over each of the strings in the vector and copy it into the `char **__ptr` of the struct while incrementing the size simultaneously. Repeat this with each of the vectors.

Comment: i don't disagree, but my C/C++ is a lil rusty. how would one put a vector<string> into a char **?