# C Error: invalid types 'double[int]' for array subscript

Tags: c, arrays

I am creating a program to read a file and stores its data in an array and then create a function to compute its derivative, was able to read the files and create the derivative, but when I try to create an external function to calculate the value of derivative of the function I encounter the following error: "[error] invalid types 'double [int]' for array subscript" Ja tried to solve it in different ways, but without success.

```
#include "biblioteca.h"

int main(){

FILE* fp;
fp = fopen("entrada.txt","rt");
if (fp == NULL) {
printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo!\n");
exit(1); }

int i; //grau do polinomio
fscanf(fp,"%d",&i);
printf("i = [%d]\n",i);
double mat[i-1][i+1];
int c=0; //colunas

while(c<i+1){
fscanf(fp,"%lf",&mat[0][c]);
c++;
}   

int h=i; //h grau do expoente
for(int l=0;l<i-1;l++){ //l linhas
int k=0; //contador
for(c=h;c>0;c--){
    mat[l+1][c-1]=mat[l][c]*(h-k);
    k++;
}
h--;
}

int k=0; //linhas
while(k<i){
for(c=0;c<i+1;c++){
    printf("%lf \t",mat[k][c]);}
k++;
printf("\n");
}

double x=mat[i-1][0]*-1/mat[i-1][1];
printf("x = %lf\n",x);

double x1;
x1=f(**mat,i,1,x);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

library:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double f(double mat,int i,int t,double x){
double x1=0;
for(int g=0;g<i+1;g++){
    if(x==0){
        x1=0;
    }
    if(x!=0){
        x1=mat[t][g]*pow(x,g)+x1;
    }
}
return x1;
```

}

Comment: `double f(double mat,int i,int t,double x){` -> `double f(int i, double mat[i-1][i+1], int t,double x){`

Comment: and call `x1=f(i, mat, 1, x);` BTW when `double x[A][B]`, must be 1st index < A. I seems that your code is  to be often beyond the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call **f function**, you pass `double mat` as argument. That passes just a double value as argument not the entire matrix. You need to change `double mat` to `double **mat` in *f declaration*.

```
double f(double** mat,int i,int t,double x)
```

However for that to work you need to allocate the matrix dynamically.

```
double** mat = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*) * (i-1));
for (int l = 0; l < i-1; i++)
   mat[l] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * (i+1));
```

Then I'll let you learn how to free the memory :)

You created mat statically so it's difficult to pass it as an argument. However you can also look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557812/c-dynamic-static-arrays-as-parameters-to-functions)** if you really want to pass the static 2D array as parameter.

Comment: i change to double f(double **mat,int i,int t,double x) and another error appears.
[Error] cannot convert 'double (*)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)(i + 1)) + -1)) + 1)]' to 'double**' for argument '1' to 'double f(double**, int, int, double)'

Comment: Can you explain more what you have changed? Please read my updated post.

Comment: You can't pass a two-dimensional array of `double` to a function expecting type `double **`, that's never going to work.

Comment: had made the wrong change, I let x1 f as you said, now I change double mat [i-1] [i + 1] to double ** mat [i-1] [i + 1] and when I test program appears "[Error] invalid operands of types 'double **' and 'int' to binary 'operator *'" lines 26 and 40.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths sorry. Missed that. I'm updating my post.